# Express-validator does not catches errors

Tags: node.js, express, express-session, express-validator

In node 8.11.1, express 4.16.3 I installed

```
"express-messages" : "*",
"connect-flash" : "*",
"express-validator" : "*",
"express-session" : "*"
```

I have a page that gets all articles `app.get('/', function(req, res){....` and also has a "New" button, for adding a new article. When hitting New, a pop-up Bootstrap form appears.

I want to check for empty form fields. The HTML form field that I check is

```
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" />
```

The form's action goes to

```
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator/check');
app.post('/add', [check('name').exists()],
function(req, res) {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  console.log(errors.isEmpty());
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    req.flash('err', 'errors'); //test
    res.redirect('/');
   }
   else {
     pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {
       if (err) {
         return console.log('db connect error '+ err);
       }
       client.query('insert into event (name) values($1)',
       [req.body.name]);
       done();
       req.flash('success', 'saved');
       res.redirect('/');
     }); //pool connect
   }//else
});
```

I am based in [this](https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator#usage). Whatever I do, the `console.log(errors.isEmpty());` is always TRUE, so I end up saving to my DB empty fields. So, the express-validator does not catches errors ?

Also, I am not sure how to pass the `errors` back in the `/` route, so the errors can be rendered, this is why I just use `req.flash('err', 'errors');` for now. Do I use `req.flash` like for the success part?

Please help me debug this.Thanks

Comment: What is the value of the "errors" object after running validationResult(req)?

Comment: @ElliotBlackburn This is what `console.log` gives `{ isEmpty: [Function],
  array: [Function],
  mapped: [Function],
  formatWith: [Function],
  throw: [Function] }
`

Answer (score 3):

express-validator maintainer here.

#### Regarding express-validator letting empty strings come through

`check()` will create a validator chain for *something in the request* named `name`.
It's not assertive of the location of the field, it could be `req.query.name` or `req.body.name`, for example.
If you want specifically `req.body`, then use the other chain creator `body()`.

Then, even if you do have `name` in `req.body`, please note that `check('name').exists()` is not validating its content. It's simply checking it exists, as the name says.
If you want to check that it has some content, whatever that is, you can use `check('name').not().isEmpty()`.

#### Regarding passing the errors to the redirected page

You can call either `errors.array()` or `errors.mapped()` to get the actual errors (please check the [`Validation Chain API`](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/validation-chain-api.html) for details).

I haven't used `req.flash`, so you should test if you can pass an JS object in there, or if you can only pass strings.
If you must use a string, then `JSON.stringify`/`JSON.parse` should be your friends to transport your errors.